# Make Cross Domain Call with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, mapserver

Since we are using the OpenLayers 3 framework to make our calls to...in my case MapServer...

```
//******* MapServer water Layer ***************
            var Water = new ol.layer.Tile({
                name: 'Water',
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: mapServerPath.ResponseString + 'MappingWater.map&',
                    params: { 'LAYERS': 'Water', 'FORMAT': 'image/png', 'TILED': true },
                    serverType: 'mapserver'
                })                   
            });
            control.map.addLayer(Water);
```

How do we make this call CORS enabled so that the canvas does not get tainted?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Set crossOrigin: 'anonymous' on the source as a config option, and make sure you have CORS headers enabled on your MapServer instance (at the webserver level).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm new to CORS can you explain what needs to be done in a little more detail?